# El resultado de la operacion me da en negativo en javascript

Tags: javascript

Teniendo en cuenta que:

- mi número base es mayor y siempre será mayor, y que
- el input, sera menor que base,

¿por qué obtengo números negativos?.

> Contenido de int.js:

```
function calculo()
{
    var n1 = parseInt(document.getElementById('n1').value);
    var n2 = parseFloat(document.getElementById('n2').value);
    var base1  = parseInt(document.getElementById('const1').value);
    var base2  = parseFloat(document.getElementById('const2').value);

    n1 -= base1;
    n2 -= base2;

    alert(n1);
    alert(n2);
} console.log(calculo);
```

Comment: Primero que nada el console log no devolvera nada pk no retornas nada en esa funcion `calculo()`, y segundo si base1 es mayor a n1 o base2 es mayor que n2 entonces n1 o n2 seran negativos

Comment: En realidad console.log devuelve la función calculo (se imprimirá el código) porque no se influyeron los paréntesis.

Comment: Las preguntas que buscan ayuda con la depuración de código deben incluir un [mcve]. A esta pregunta le falta el html

Comment: Para que no te de negativo al mayor de los dos le tenes que restar el menor. Si a y b son dos número podes hacer que el resultado r = a > b ? a - b : b - a;

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Obtienes negativos porque la siguiente línea:

```
n1 -= base1;
```

Equivale a:

```
n1 = n1 - base1;
```

Por tanto si `base` siempre será mayor a `n`, siempre obtendrás números negativos, pues 4 - 6 = -2

Para solucionarlo deberás invertir el orden y restar `n` a `base` (6-4 = 2):

```
n1 = base1 - n1
```